# Append to variable filename in Bash

Tags: bash, zsh

Why does this work:

```
echo "foo" >> ~/Desktop/sf-speedtest-output.csv
```

But this does not?

```
outputFile="~/Desktop/sf-speedtest-output.csv"
echo "foo" >> $outputFile # Error: No Such file or directory
```

I have tried it in `${}`, `$()`, `""`. Is this not an escaping issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~`-expansion won't happen inside a quoted string. You can get away with this:

```
outputFile=~/"Desktop/..."
```

Or this:

```
outputFile="$HOME/Desktop/..."
```

See [Tilde expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/tilde) or the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) for more details.

Comment: Great answer, and avoids hard-coding the user name. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Because tilde `~` expansions are not done in double quotes `"`

> If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character (‘~’), all of the
>   characters up to the first unquoted slash (or all characters, if there
>   is no unquoted slash) are considered a tilde-prefix

This should work in turn

```
outputFile="/home/user/Desktop/sf-speedtest-output.csv"
echo "foo" >> $outputFile
```

Or

```
outputFile=~/"Desktop/sf-speedtest-output.csv"
echo "foo" >> $outputFile
```